# Message DIV Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following javascript it pops up a message on the screen, but always over the top of the previous messageDiv if it hasn't been removed yet.

**I am trying to figure out how to get the messageDiv to either push the previous div down until it disappears and then takes the previous MessageDiv's place, or show up just below the current one on the page moving down just below the previous one as new ones appear.**

```
function pushDev(){
    $.post( "#cgi.SCRIPT_NAME#", {fileId: "#fileIdIn#", action: "migrateFileDev"}, function(data){
        $("body").prepend("<div class='pageMessage' id='messageDiv'>" + data + "</div>");
        setTimeout(function(){$('#messageDiv').remove()}, 6000);
    });
}

function savePage(){
    var code = editor.getValue();
    $.post( "#cgi.SCRIPT_NAME#", {fileIdIn: "#fileIdIn#", filePath: "#path#", action: "savePage", editText: code }, function(data){
        $("body").prepend("<div class='pageMessage' id='messageDiv'>Saved</div>");
        setTimeout(function(){$('#messageDiv').remove()}, 6000);
    });
}


.pageMessage{
    /*position:fixed;*/
    /*top: 15%;*/
    /*right: 8%;*/
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    opacity: 0.9;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 8px;
    width: auto;
    height:auto;
    border:solid;
    border-color: #00A3DD;
    border-width: 3px;
    z-index: 1000;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: you can not select an item with double ##  ... `$('##messageDiv').remove()`

Comment: yes and no, that is how coldfusion escapes out a pound sign if you are in a <cfoutput></cfoutput>  I have edited the post to remove the coldfusion  part of the the code.

Comment: what is your Question??

Comment: See bolded part of question above.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are running into a problem because you have multiple elements with the same ID and when your setTimeout callback executes, it removes the newest message rather than the oldest one. Only one element with a given ID is allowed in HTML. You need to figure out a different way of finding the div that should be deleted for the particular timeout, for example (I got rid of the irrelevant AJAX code):

```
function pushDev(){
    var messageDiv = $("<div class='pageMessage'>Data</div>")
    $("body").prepend(messageDiv);
    setTimeout(function(){messageDiv.remove()}, 6000);
}

function savePage(){
    var messageDiv = $("<div class='pageMessage'>Saved</div>")
    $("body").prepend(messageDiv);
    setTimeout(function(){messageDiv.remove()}, 6000);
}
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rzvjefna/).

Comment: Driving, so will take a look at soon, but the removing the div, hasn't been a problem,  its that all the message divs stack on top of each other.

Comment: This code does have merit, however like I mentioned at just glancing at the code yesterday, it doesn't answer the question.

The issue is that all the DIVs created are stacked right on top of each other.  I would like them to cascade down the page as they are created at the very least so they don't cover the previously placed DIV.